# Problems with long double in gcc 4.6.1 (linux)

Tags: c, gcc, type-conversion, linux-mint

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long double n = (long double)1208925819614629174706175; // (1<<80)-1 (generated in python)
    printf("%LG\n",n);
}
```

On compiling this with gcc, I get a warning

```
test.c:5:31: warning: integer constant is too large for its type [enabled by default]
```

On running it prints `-1`

On doing a `sizeof(long double)`, it prints `12`.
 So a signed `long double` should accomodate **(1<<83)-1** right?

How do I get it working correctly?

PS: The original problem I was working on, dealt with storing signed integers as large as **12*(10<sup>18</sup>**). I don't want to write multiplication, addition, and other calculation routines. So how do I do it?

Comment: "The original problem I was working on, dealt with storing signed **integers**."  Are you aware that `long double` is not an integer type?

Comment: I just realized! Well, can you suggest some method so that I can store 12*(10**18) without using arrays for numbers? Does any method even exist?

Comment: Long double will handle 10**300 and above, that's not what the compiler is complaining about.  It says the integer that you are trying to cast into a long is too big for an integer. ( hint - add a decimal point )

Comment: If you want to store an integer up to 12*(10^18), why don't you use `unsigned long long`, it can store up to ~18*(10^18). And you may want to use constant numbers type specifier, like this: 1.5f (float), 100ll (long long)

Comment: @saeedn I've already tried `unsigned long long`, to no avail. Anyways, looks like I'll have to figure it out myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long double will handle 10**300 and above, that's not what the compiler is complaining about. It says the integer that you are trying to cast into a long is too big for an integer. ( hint - add a decimal point ) – starbolin

Answer (score 2):

Starbolin is correct, but I think a detailed explanation of this expression is needed:

In C, numeric constants (without a decimal point) are of types either `int` or `long`, depending on the value.
The constant you use, `1208925819614629174706175`, is too big even for `long`, so it's truncated.
All this happens before casting to `long double` and assigning to `n`.
When floating point types get into the picture, the numeric constant has already been truncated, and the lost bits can't come back.

This happens because C is a simple language, which follows simply defined steps during compilation. The compiler doesn't "peek ahead" to see that a numeric constant will be cast to `long double`. It first treats it as `long`, then proceeds.

Comment: Or `long long`, since C99. And if they have a suffix `U`, or are given in hexadecimal or octal, that adds the unsigned types to the possibilities (an `L` suffix removes types smaller than `long int`, `LL` smaller than `long long int` from the possibilities).

Comment: @DanielFischer, you're right, but I'm tried to keep things simple. Another strange thing is that `3*10^9` is `int` (though it's too big for `int`), while `5*10^9` is `long` (or `long long`).

Comment: Thought you'd be aware of it, but felt obliged to complete the list. For me `printf("%zu\n",sizeof 3000000000);` prints 8, so it'd be a `long`, not `int` here (gcc-4.5.1). What compiler says it's `int`?

Comment: gcc 4.3.3, with default flags (but not with -std=c99).

Comment: Odd. I get 8 for the size even with `-std=c89` (or without any flags), as I should. Is it a 32-bit system or 64?

Comment: 32bit. Maybe it's just a bug, fixed in 4.5?